# Assigning data in a new table to an existing foreign key in a for loop

Tags: oracle, loops, insert, foreign-keys

I was wondering if there was a way to assign new data in a table to an existing foreign key.
For example if I use the following loop to assign randomly generated numbers to columns in the customer table, how would I be able to link cust_id, which I have assigned as a foreign key in the Sales table, with new data created each time a new sale is made?

```
CUSTOMER:
DECLARE
        v_cust_id          NUMBER(4) NOT NULL := 0000;
        v_cust_name        VARCHAR2(30);
        v_cust_add         VARCHAR2(30);
        v_phone            VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
        FOR v IN 1 .. 2000 --Loop 2000 times to create data for the 2000 customers in the database.
        LOOP
                v_cust_id := v_cust_id + 1;
                v_cust_name := dbms_random.string('U',5);
                v_cust_add := dbms_random.string('A',15);
                v_phone := dbms_random.value(1000000,9999999);
                        INSERT INTO customer (cust_id, cust_name, cust_add, phone)
                                VALUES (v_cust_id, v_cust_name, v_cust_add, v_phone);
        END LOOP;
END;
/

SALES:
DECLARE
        v_sale_id                 NUMBER(4) NOT NULL := ;
        v_sale_price              NUMBER(8,2);
        v_sale_date               DATE;
        v_no_of_prods             NUMBER(4);
        v_prod_id                 NUMBER(4);
        v_desp_id                 NUMBER(4);
        v_cust_id                 NUMBER(4);
BEGIN
        FOR v IN 1 .. 10
        LOOP
                v_sale_id :=
                v_sale_price
                v_sale_date :=
                v_no_of_products :=
                v_prod_id :=
                v_desp_id :=
                v_cust_id :=
                        INSERT INTO sales (sale_id, sale_price, sale_date, no_of_prods, prod_id, desp_id, cust_id)
                                VALUES (v_sale_id, v_sale_price, v_sale_date, v_no_of_prods, v_prod_id, v_desp_id, v_cust_id);
        END LOOP;
END;
\
```

Comment: Try formatting your code. I suspect you won't get many answers when your code is a thrown-together mess like this.

Comment: I was the person who posted the question above.
I will be using the random generator to assign values to the sales table as well. But what I was wondering is how you would assign a cust_id to newly generated data into the sales table.
Also, what does the line: where mod(cust_id,13) =0; mean?
Thank you.

Comment: where mod(cust_id,13) =0 uses modulus to generate a random sales record for every thirteenth customer record.

Comment: so how would I incorporate that into my for loop insert code?

Comment: Why do you want to loop insert? I provided two sql inserts that you can run outside any loop. I provided an sql solution, not a pl/sql solution.

Comment: Because I use insert ... select I don't have to loop.

Comment: But what if I wanted to make it in a loop? Because I have to create a lot of test data for the database. Thank you!

Comment: You can put the insert into sales.. statements inside a loop. I used mod(cust_id,...) =0 to make your sales data more jagged and more realistic. Else every customer will have exactly ten sales.

Comment: How would you suggest I would go about doing the following for the v_cust_id := part? 

DECLARE
        v_sale_id           NUMBER(4) NOT NULL := 6000;
        v_sale_price        NUMBER(8,2);
        v_sale_date         DATE;
        v_cust_id           b.cust_id%TYPE;       

BEGIN
        FOR v IN 1 .. 10
        LOOP
       v_sale_id := v_sale_id + 1;
       v_sale_price := dbms_random.value(0000,9999);
       v_sale_date := SYSDATE;
       v_cust_id := 
insert into n(sale_id, sale_price, sale_date, cust_id)
values(v_sale_id, v_sale_price, v_sale_date v_cust_id);
end loop;
end;
/

Comment: I was thinking of maybe creating a cursor to link to it?
Something like: CURSOR cust_id_cur 
         IS
         SELECT cust_id FROM b;

Comment: I've provided a full example and I inculded two create table statements. There is no need for a cursor.

Answer (score 2):

You are generating test data to do some kind of performance test?

Let's first generate 2000 customers.

(untested)

```
insert into customer 
(cust_id, cust_name, cust_add, phone)
select 
level l, 
dbms_random.string('U',5), 
dbms_random.string('A',15), 
dbms_random.value(1000000,9999999) 
from dual
connect by level <= 2000;
```

Now you can genereate sales data by selecting from the customer table:

```
insert into sales 
(sale_id, sale_price, sale_date, no_of_prods, prod_id, desp_id, cust_id)
select sale_id_sequence.nextval , dbms_random. ...., cust_id
from customer;

insert into sales 
(sale_id, sale_price, sale_date, no_of_prods, prod_id, desp_id, cust_id)
select sale_id_sequence.nextval , dbms_random. ...., cust_id
from customer
where mod(cust_id,2) =0;

insert into sales 
(sale_id, sale_price, sale_date, no_of_prods, prod_id, desp_id, cust_id)
select sale_id_sequence.nextval , dbms_radom. ...., cust_id
from customer
where mod(cust_id,7) =0;

insert into sales 
(sale_id, sale_price, sale_date, no_of_prods, prod_id, desp_id, cust_id)
select sale_id_sequence.nextval , dbms_random. ...., cust_id
from customer
where mod(cust_id,13) =0;

commit;
```

I assume there is a sequence to create a sale id.

**edit1 improvement:**

```
create table customer 
( cust_id number(10)
, cust_name varchar2(50)
, cust_add  varchar2(30)
, cust_phone varchar2(10)
);

create sequence cust_id_seq;

create table sales
( sale_id number(10)
, prod_no number(10)
, cust_id number(10)
);

create sequence sale_id_seq;

begin

  insert into customer 
  select cust_id_seq.nextval 
  ,      dbms_random.string('U',5)
  ,      dbms_random.string('A',15) 
  ,      trunc(dbms_random.value(1000000,9999999))
  from   dual
  connect by level < 2000;

  for i in 1..10 loop

    insert into sales 
    select sale_id_seq.nextval
    ,      trunc(dbms_random.value(1,100))
    ,      cust_id
    from   customer;

    insert into sales 
    select sale_id_seq.nextval
    ,      trunc(dbms_random.value(1,100))
    ,      cust_id
    from   customer
    where  mod(cust_id+i,2)=0;

    insert into sales 
    select sale_id_seq.nextval
    ,      trunc(dbms_random.value(1,100))
    ,      cust_id
    from   customer
    where  mod(cust_id+i,7)=0; 

  end loop;

end;
/

commit;

select count(*) from customer;

select count(*) from sales;
```